# Why background and buttons cause running slow?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, background

When i change the background and buttons of my android project,it really runs slow.It runs too fast using blue background and buttons but it runs too slow when using metal background and silver buttons.why?How can i run much faster using metal background and silver buttons?

Blue background-runs fast

[image: Blue background-runs fast]

Metal background-runs slow

[image: Metal background-runs slow]

xml files of metal background buttons
BUTTON DESIGN 1

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#AFAFAF"
        android:angle="90"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:color="#AFAFAF"
        android:width="5dp"
         />
    </shape>
```

BUTTON DESIGN 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="90"
        android:type="linear"
        />
</shape>
```

BUTTON SELECTOR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_design"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_design2"
        />
</selector>
```

Comment: What are the sizes of both background images?

Comment: blue is 101 kb metal is 230 kb.But i tried different backgrounds with different backgrounds but it still works slow.

Comment: Even 101 kb is quite a lot in this case, try to use smaller graphics, or even gradients.

Comment: when i use blue background with buttons which belongs to metal backgorund,it runs slowly.

Comment: What are the sizes of graphics that you use for buttons?

Comment: @Egor i dont use any graphics for buttons only a button selector

Comment: We would need to see some code and layouts. Are you switching things dynamically while the app is running or are you explicitly changing code and rebuilding the project each time?

Comment: İ will add xml codes.Im rebuilding project each time

Comment: @zgc7009 added button xml files of metal background

Comment: can you post your Java code? and what do you mean "it runs slowly"? The button animations? Other animations? background processing?